# How to change style of a clicked element in nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have this code for add an event when you click in an element of the chart

`chart.multibar.dispatch.on('elementClick', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
 });`

I need to change the fill color of the clicked element

Comment: `d3.select(this).attr("fill", "red")`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff it is .attr or .style ?

Comment: Either should work unless you've set the default in CSS. Then use `.style()`.